# Bootstrap popover dynamic size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a dynamic menu system for Composite C1 using Bootstrap 3.3.1 popovers. The dynamic content is working fine, but I can't seem to get the popover width to re-size correctly.

I can set an absolute size with `.popover-menu-markup .popover{ width: whatever}`, but I want the width to be based on the content. If I set `width: auto`, the popover is based on the popover-title, not the popover-content.

Any ideas?

## EDIT

Sorry, the JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rebeccamarye/x075bm6x/2/

The example shows a single paragraph as the content, but in the actual page there's a bunch of divs with {display: inline-block}, but I think this shows the problem...the popover needs to expand to slightly less than the width of the page.

Comment: Can you JSFiddle it?

Comment: One question per question, please. I removed your second question; feel free to post it as a new question if relevant.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/x075bm6x/7/

**JQ**

```
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').on('shown.bs.popover',function(e){
    var $link =$(this);

    var winW=$(window).width();    
    var poL=$link.offset().left+$link.width();        
    var newW=winW-poL-60;        

    var poId=$link.attr('aria-describedby');
    var $po=$('#'+poId);

    console.log(poId+': '+winW+' L: '+poL+' > '+newW);

    //$po.width(newW);
    $po.find('.popover-content').width(newW)
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.popover{width:auto!important; max-width: none}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, but I want to set the width dynamically. Your version doesn't appear to accomplish anything that setting the width in the style does. Or did I miss something?

Comment: In this function you can calculate the width. And as I wrote in response did not understand from your question that the width should be: the width of the page or width titles. So I put only variable with a specific value.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did miss that (duh...) Unfortunately, it doesn't work. shown.bs.popover flashes the original (incorrect) width and then puts the little triangle-pointer-thingy in the wrong place. show.bs.popover has no effect.  I do appreciate you looking at the problem, though...

Comment: Well, we're making progress...using the technique you outlined I can set the width correctly, but if you place the popover on the bottom, the first time it's opened, the pointer-thingy is in the wrong place. The second time you open it, it's fine...http://jsfiddle.net/rebeccamarye/5jcewsva/

Comment: there is no end to your wishes :)